# Pointers and assignment, how does it work with different types?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm doing "Learn C the hard way" for self-study coming from knowing a bit of Python. I have read several tutorials, but I can't get my head around how pointers and assignment works. I understand that if you dereference the pointer, you can directly give it a value as in:

```
int *anint = 42;
```

But what about specifically referencing the memory location of an already-created variable?
Specifically, I tried:

```
char *pointer_to_strlit;
char *strlit = "some stuff";
pointer_to_strlit = &strlit;
```

Why does the following cause a segfault after I do this:

```
printf("I print strlit: %s\nI print it again by pointing to it: %s\nI print where the pointer is pointing: %p\n", strlit, *pointer_to_strlit, pointer_to_strlit);
```

The types in C seem really hard tell how they will behave and how to use pointers to reference the specific types. Is there a clear guide that specifically outlines the syntax for pointing to each different datatype (`char`, `*char`, `*char[]`, `int`, `struct`, `void`, `null`, functions, etc.)? Even a list of steps that would help me understand the rule set would be useful.

Comment: ALWAYS turn on all the warnings your compiler can give you (`-Wall` with gcc; other compilers have different options) and ALWAYS pay attention to what the warnings say.  The warnings you get from the above code should tell you exactly what you are getting confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hang in there! Pointers will make sense after more practice. But when in doubt, try to reason about what each value means. Using pen and paper to try to draw each byte in memory *really* helps.

`char *pointer_to_strlit;` - here you declare a pointer to a character. As you probably already know, a string in C is represented by a pointer to the first character of that string. The string is expected to be null-terminated. This means that eventually there should be an ASCII `0` character indicating that the string has ended.

`char *strlit = "some stuff";` - your program's memory will contain characters for this string (11 characters to be exact -- 10 for the text you see, and 1 for the null terminator). Here you declare another pointer, this time pointing to first character "s" from that string.

`pointer_to_strlit = &strlit;` - this sets the value of `pointer_to_strlit` to the **address of** the pointer `strlit`. This is probably not what you want here.

If things get confusing, try to think of each pointer as a plain old number -- that's essentially what a pointer is, a huge number representing an address in memory. Let's look at the above again:

`char *pointer_to_strlit;` - Here the value of `pointer_to_strlit` is undefined since you didn't set it yet.

`char *strlit = "some stuff";` - Let's say the address of the first "s" is `1234500`. The value of `strlit` will be that number, `1234500`.

`pointer_to_strlit = &strlit;` - But what is the address of `strlit` itself? It's some other value, let's say `1234600`. The value of `pointer_to_strlit` will now be `1234600`.

Try to print `pointer_to_strlit` as a `%s` now, and your program will crash -- at the address `1234600` is not the first character of a string, but another number -- one of the bytes of the huge number, the pointer. The code will try to traverse what *it thinks is a string* to look for the null-terminator, eventually crashing when it reaches inaccessible memory.

Comment: `char *strlit = "some stuff"; - this places some characters (11 to be exact -- 10 for the string, and 1 for the null terminator) to the current stack.` Quite sure this is not on stack. You only declare a pointer to a constant string.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right, thanks, given that this is a string literal. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the very easy to understand wording of your answer.  Is there any way to point at a string literal as if it were an array and result in %s actually getting to the null byte at the end of the string?  It's outside the scope of the question, so I closed the topic anyway.

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful! Yeah, you can just say `pointer_to_strlit = strlit`. Note, no `&`. Reason through it like this: `strlit` points to the first character of that string literal (let's say, address 1234500). Basically, the value of `strlit` is `1234500`. Here you set `pointer_to_strlit` to have that exact same value, and so it will also points to that string literal. Again, just think of the pointers as numbers and much of the magic will disappear. :)

Comment: @Ceryn: You have to declare `pointer_to_strlit` as `char**`. So that when you dereference it with `*`, it will take `sizeof(char*)` bytes underneath - instead of `sizeof(char)` bytes when you declare it as `char*`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't think the OP wanted a pointer-to-a-pointer, just another pointer that points to the same string. :)

Comment: @Dennis: I think the OP is experimenting around with pointers to learn, so I just give another alternative to make the code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *anint = 42;
```

42 is an integer literal and `anint` is supposed to hold the address pointing to an integer and not by integer itself.

```
char *pointer_to_strlit;
char *strlit = "some stuff";    // Should be const char *strlit = "some stuff";
pointer_to_strlit = &strlit;    // Wrong
```

`&strlit` gives address of pointer ( i.e., char ** ) while `pointer_to_strlit` is of type char*. So, it should be

```
pointer_to_strlit = strlit;
```

String literals reside in read only location. Turn on the warnings and compiler should give you some decent messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *anint = 42;
```

This declaration is incorrect.  `anint` is a pointer to an int, but you've initialized it as an int.

```
char *pointer_to_strlit;
char *strlit = "some stuff";
```

These declarations are fine.  `"some stuff"` is a string literal, which in C is a `char *`, so it's fine to initialize `strlit` with it.

```
pointer_to_strlit = &strlit;
```

This is incorrect.  `&strlit` is a `char**`, since it's the address of a `char*`.

```
printf(
    "I print strlit: %s\n"
    "I print it again by pointing to it: %s\n"
    "I print where the pointer is pointing: %p\n", 
    strlit, *pointer_to_strlit, pointer_to_strlit
);
```

Here you use `strlit` as `%s`, which is fine.  Then you use `*pointer_to_strlit` as `%s`, which is bad: `%s` expects a pointer to a null-terminated string, you gave it a `char`, so it segfaults.

Comment: This is probably outside the scope of the question, but what variable could I pass to printf that would actually cause printf to print the entire string literal that the pointer points at?